# Facing android.view.InflateException: in my xml

Tags: java, android

I had use the material widget in my fragment xml but got a error on inflating that xml. I stuck about last 4 hours in there. here is my xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/education_inputtxt_field"
    style="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.TextInputLayout.Rounded"
   ......
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edu_level_txt"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/looking_for_inputtextfield"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edu_selection"
        ........
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/down_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/edu_level_txt"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/edu_level_txt" >

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

`</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>` In theme
[App:theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imXXS.png)
There is a error i facing on inflating that xml [Process: Myapp.example.metrimonialapp, PID: 27774
android.view.InflateException:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3rZB.jpg)

I want to customize the design of material widgets text input layout but it tackle an error on inflate the xml.